# SwiftUI: How to use the fileExporter modifier for multiple file types

Tags: ios, macos, swiftui, save-as, uttype

I am trying to use SwiftUI's the `.fileExporter` modifier with an item that confirms to the [`Transferable protocol`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coretransferable/transferable#) for multiple types like this:

```
    FileRepresentation(exportedContentType: .pdf) { (item: MyItem) in
        SentTransferredFile(item.webPDFPathURL)
    }
```

This is how I use the `fileExporter`:

```
.fileExporter(isPresented: $exportArchive, item: link, contentTypes: [UTType.webArchive, .pdf]) { 
    ... handle errors etc ...
}
```

On macOS this gives me a save panel that lets me chose the type and everything works as expected:

[image]

However on iOS and iPadOS, I don't get such an option:

[image]

Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?